# Can't resize armature without it disappearing or worse

Tags: armature

I downloaded a 3d model of a character, but it's armature is way bigger then the mesh and it's even far above and behind the mesh. I've tried to move and resize the armature in editor mode, but anytime I try to do ir, the armature just dissapears or stops working. I'm really new with the program and I just can't figure out what to do, nor have I seen anyone else with the same problem... I will leave the link to download the model if anyone wants to help...

https://www.mediafire.com/file/49llyc9laijcl2y/Jesmon_X.zip/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import DAE with **Import Units** option enabled.

[image]

Thant's what I get when imported ... (not so far or behinde as you wrote). Scale of armature is 5, but objects are 1, that make a difference. All is rotated in Y axis, but better fix that after meshes are not parented to armature. Also I would recommend to Apply Rotation (Ctrl+A) > Rotation before parenting meshes back to an armature to avoid other issues.

[image]

To fix Scale:

- Select Mesh objects and **Clear Parent** (Alt+P)
- Select Armature and **Clear Scale** (Alt+S)

Then you can parent objects back to armature (select meshes, armature as last to be an active object and press Ctrl+P).

[image]

BTW: hand seems to be in a wrong position and meshes are not assigned to the armature